# convert a html table with select to Json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have difficulties to properly export to a JSON table the content of a html table when it contains a select tag. I need the selected option value to be exported, not the full content of the select inputbox (ex: "Animal":"Dog\n    Cat\n    Hamster\n    Parrot\n    Spider\n    Goldfish" should be "Animal":"Cat")

The html code I use is:

```
<html>
<body>
  <table id="students" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
         <th> Animal </th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Oscar</td>
             <td>  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
</select>
 </td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>16.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Antonio</td>
        <td>  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster" selected>Hamster</option>
  
</select>
 </td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jessica</td>
             <td>  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

    <option value="dog" selected >Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
  
</select>
 </td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id="run">Convert!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS:

```
/*! tabletojson - v0.11.1 - Daniel White */ ! function(a) {
    "use strict";
    a.fn.tableToJSON = function(b) {
        var c = {
            ignoreColumns: [],
            onlyColumns: null,
            ignoreHiddenRows: !0,
            ignoreEmptyRows: !1,
            headings: null,
            allowHTML: !1,
            includeRowId: !1,
            textDataOverride: "data-override",
            textExtractor: null
        };
        b = a.extend(c, b);
        var d = function(a) {
                return void 0 !== a && null !== a
            },
            e = function(c) {
                return d(b.onlyColumns) ? -1 === a.inArray(c, b.onlyColumns) : -1 !== a.inArray(c, b.ignoreColumns)
            },
            f = function(b, c) {
                var e = {},
                    f = 0;
                return a.each(c, function(a, c) {
                    f < b.length && d(c) && (e[b[f]] = c, f++)
                }), e
            },
            g = function(c, d, e) {
                var f = a(d),
                    g = b.textExtractor,
                    h = f.attr(b.textDataOverride);
                return null === g || e ? a.trim(h || (b.allowHTML ? f.html() : d.textContent || f.text()) || "") : a.isFunction(g) ? a.trim(h || g(c, f)) : "object" == typeof g && a.isFunction(g[c]) ? a.trim(h || g[c](c, f)) : a.trim(h || (b.allowHTML ? f.html() : d.textContent || f.text()) || "")
            },
            h = function(c, d) {
                var e = [],
                    f = b.includeRowId,
                    h = "boolean" == typeof f ? f : "string" == typeof f ? !0 : !1,
                    i = "string" == typeof f == !0 ? f : "rowId";
                return h && "undefined" == typeof a(c).attr("id") && e.push(i), a(c).children("td,th").each(function(a, b) {
                    e.push(g(a, b, d))
                }), e
            },
            i = function(a) {
                var c = a.find("tr:first").first();
                return d(b.headings) ? b.headings : h(c, !0)
            },
            j = function(c, h) {
                var i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p = [],
                    q = 0,
                    r = [];
                return c.children("tbody,*").children("tr").each(function(c, e) {
                    if (c > 0 || d(b.headings)) {
                        var f = b.includeRowId,
                            h = "boolean" == typeof f ? f : "string" == typeof f ? !0 : !1;
                        n = a(e);
                        var r = n.find("td").length === n.find("td:empty").length ? !0 : !1;
                        !n.is(":visible") && b.ignoreHiddenRows || r && b.ignoreEmptyRows || n.data("ignore") && "false" !== n.data("ignore") || (q = 0, p[c] || (p[c] = []), h && (q += 1, "undefined" != typeof n.attr("id") ? p[c].push(n.attr("id")) : p[c].push("")), n.children().each(function() {
                            for (o = a(this); p[c][q];) q++;
                            if (o.filter("[rowspan]").length)
                                for (k = parseInt(o.attr("rowspan"), 10) - 1, m = g(q, o), i = 1; k >= i; i++) p[c + i] || (p[c + i] = []), p[c + i][q] = m;
                            if (o.filter("[colspan]").length)
                                for (k = parseInt(o.attr("colspan"), 10) - 1, m = g(q, o), i = 1; k >= i; i++)
                                    if (o.filter("[rowspan]").length)
                                        for (l = parseInt(o.attr("rowspan"), 10), j = 0; l > j; j++) p[c + j][q + i] = m;
                                    else p[c][q + i] = m;
                            m = p[c][q] || g(q, o), d(m) && (p[c][q] = m), q++
                        }))
                    }
                }), a.each(p, function(c, g) {
                    if (d(g)) {
                        var i = d(b.onlyColumns) || b.ignoreColumns.length ? a.grep(g, function(a, b) {
                                return !e(b)
                            }) : g,
                            j = d(b.headings) ? h : a.grep(h, function(a, b) {
                                return !e(b)
                            });
                        m = f(j, i), r[r.length] = m
                    }
                }), r
            },
            k = i(this);
        return j(this, k)
    }
}(jQuery);

// Code goes here

$('#run').click(function() {
    var table = $('#students').tableToJSON({
        extractor: function($index, $cell) {
            return {
                name: $cell.find('td').value
            };
        }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(table));
});
```

you can check the result in the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/rdugert/pen/qBrVGVw)

Comment: First question: Why are you writing code using variable like a, b, c...? It makes it way harder to understand and to decode.

Comment: this is coming from the original code of tabletojson https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@1.0.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is use the index in the extractor. When index is one return the value of the select, otherwise return the cell text

```js
$('#run').click(function() {
  var table = $('#students').tableToJSON({
    extractor: function($index, $cell) {
      if ($index == 1) {
        return $cell.find('select').val()
      }
      return $cell.text()
    }
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(table));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@1.0.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js" integrity="sha256-H8xrCe0tZFi/C2CgxkmiGksqVaxhW0PFcUKZJZo1yNU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="students" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th> Animal </th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Oscar</td>
      <td>
        <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

          <option value="dog">Dog</option>
          <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
          <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>16.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Antonio</td>
      <td>
        <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

          <option value="dog">Dog</option>
          <option value="cat">Cat</option>
          <option value="hamster" selected>Hamster</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td>
        <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

          <option value="dog" selected>Dog</option>
          <option value="cat">Cat</option>
          <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="run">Convert!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that for a `<select>`, you need to get the `selected option`. Otherwise it will return all option values as you've described. Unless you absolutely need to use `.tableToJSON()`, which looks like alot of obfuscated overhead, I simplified the code into something a little more easier to follow. Also this is more flexible than the current accepted answer in that you could move the select to another column and it will still work.

```js
$('#run').on('click', function() {
  let items = $('thead th').get().map(th => th.textContent.trim()),
      json = [];
      
  $('tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {
    json[row] = {};
    
    $(tr).find('td').each(function(index, td) {
      json[row][items[index]] = td.firstElementChild ?
        td.firstElementChild.selectedOptions[0].value : td.textContent;
    });
  });
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <table id="students" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
         <th> Animal </th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Oscar</td>
             <td>  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
</select>
 </td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>16.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Antonio</td>
        <td>  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster" selected>Hamster</option>
  
</select>
 </td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jessica</td>
             <td>  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">

    <option value="dog" selected >Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
  
</select>
 </td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id="run">Convert!</button>
</body>
</html>
```